# Find Category by ID in Magento Backend

Tags: magento-1, backend

How can I find a category by its ID in the magento backend?

Comment: From what I know, you cannot.

Comment: @Marius too sad, I need that all the time. If that is true I have to create a small PHP file where I can search for IDs as soon as I have some time.

Comment: I understand your frustration. I needed something like this a lot of times. To find it easier, I usually looked in one of the flat categories table and got the path to the category from the `url_path` column. Maybe it helps for now. And if you implement a search for categories, put it on github :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

and now it is possible :)

https://github.com/ProxiBlue/jumptocatid

(felt like something quick to work on before shut eye)

This places an input box above the category tree in admin, and allows you to jump to any category id entered.

[image]

Largely untested, so please adjust as needed

Comment: Nice. just very very nice. +2. :)

Comment: hehe, you just done my work. Nice and thanks+1. I will test it next week

Comment: Thanks for this code @ProxiBlue! I got sick of trying to find what category had a particular ID so this was a nearly perfect solution (even worked without changes on Magento 1.9.3.2). I also fiddled around with it until I realised I could do a store switch without switching stores, which selects the category AND updates the tree. Made a pull request, but I'm pretty new to github so I'm not sure if I did it right :P

Comment: I have installed it but there is no such input box above the category tree in admin.I also have clear cache

Answer (score 10):

In the Magento backend, browse to Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management.

On this page you can search on ID Path. If you just type `category/*` where `*` is your category id, the request path will show you the category name.

Comment: Nice work around +1

Answer (score 0):

in magento 2.1.5 you have 2 options :

1 - in your dashboard go to Products>categories , click the subcategory and watch the URL on your browser ..

for example :
catalog/category/edit/key/046d4ea88011b68906d6d75032d0f478bf303fa968f2577508f0e59d312bad3b/id/43/

this subcategory has 43 id ..

2 - open your phpmyadmin and browse for your magento database > go to Url Rewrites table > search the page for the category name , after finding it look at the entity_id column ,,,